# How to read bar code from Image using java?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, barcode

.I have to read Barcode from my android phone.There is already an open source project called Zxing to read using Intent.But i need to read to directly from my application and don't depend on other application.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100292/how-to-read-a-bar-code-and-encode-it-in-android

Comment: And if you want to directly implement in your app spend some time with Zxing code its open source you will be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the ZXing code into your app. Compile the core zxing barcode reading code into a jar file and link against that jar file. Modify the client code under the zxing/android directory to invoke the routines in the core ZXing code.

Comment: He's trying to remove dependencies. :(

Comment: No, he said he didn't want to depend on another app. Linking with the core ZXing jar adds the code into his APK - unless he doesn't want to use the ZXing code - but he didn't say that.